# C++ Compiling with Python.h Undefined Symbols

Tags: c++, python, gcc, python-2.7

So, I've been trying to start using Python.h for a little project I want to work on that seems pretty /simple/. But before I start I want to try to learn how to use Python.h.
So I found this little example online.

```
#include "Python/Python.h"  

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    Py_Initialize();  
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 'Test'");  
    PyRun_SimpleString("print str(3 + 5)"); 
    Py_Exit(0);  
}
```

Seems pretty straight forward. When i first used

```
gcc test.cpp
```

to compile, i got some undefined symbols. I quickly found out I should use

```
-lpython2.7
```

then I found out I could also use

```
-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/
```

that didn't work (I made sure that /Library/Frameworks/Python/Versions/2.7/lib/ existed)
I'm stuck, what do I do?
I get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in ccoUOSlc.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in ccoUOSlc.o
      _main in ccoUOSlc.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in ccoUOSlc.o
      CIE in ccoUOSlc.o
  "_Py_Exit", referenced from:
      _main in ccoUOSlc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT:
I just tried using the -Framework argument, and tried adding after the -L the -l python2.7 argument, and I now get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in ccfvtJ4j.o
      CIE in ccfvtJ4j.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now what?

Comment: This should work (just tested on Linux, using GCC and Python 2.7). Could you confirm that `libpython2.7.so` exists in the directory you specified with the `-L` option?

Comment: uhm. actually there is no libpython2.7.so there is libpython2.7.dylib in there though (on Mac OSX 10.6.8 if that helps)

Comment: Right. I had assumed Linux, but on MacOS that should be fine. Not sure what's causing the problem.

Comment: Note that `-L` only updates the library search path: it doesn't actually link to anything.  Were you using the `-L` option in place of or in addition to the `-l` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an Python framework installation on OS X as it appears you are based on the paths, you can use the `-framework` argument to the Apple compiler drivers:

```
cc test.cpp -framework Python
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify the directory path and library name:

```
cc test.cpp -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ -l python2.7
```

Update: With the configuration you report in the comments (`Xcode 3.2.6`, `gcc-4.2`), it appears you need to explicitly invoke the `c++` variant of `gcc`.  Either:

```
g++ test.cpp -framework Python
```

or

```
c++ test.cpp -framework Python
```

should work.

Comment: Anyone :(? I tried to provide as much information as possible. is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What compiler (`cc --version`) are you using (from what version of Xcode: `xcodebuild -version`) and what version of OS X are you using?

Comment: cc: i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Xcode: Xcode 3.2.6
Component versions: DevToolsCore-1809.0; DevToolsSupport-1806.0
BuildVersion: 10M2518
And I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8 on an iMac Early 2009 "24 computer with 4GB RAM and a 2.66GHz Intel Core Duo 2 processer.